# Split tmux windows with same keys as in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, tmux

In emacs, you split a window with `C-x 2` (one above the other) or `C-x 3` (one next to the other).

How can I get the same key bindings in `tmux`?

Also, once a window is split, in emacs you cycle through them with `C-x o`. Can I configure `tmux` to use the same key?

Comment: Have you read the man page for tmux?  It should be obvious what to do.  Unfortunately if you do it, then C-x stops working as a prefix key in Emacs because tmux will interpret it instead.

Comment: It would be nice if there were a tmux command I could use to disable those keys just for the one window in which I run emacs. Alternatively, I'd be happy to use `C-b C-x 2` instead of the normal `C-x 2` to split windows.

Answer (score 2):

Now, dreams become true:
https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/2904

My use case is:

- If a tmux pane is focused and emacsclient is not focused (eg. on termial prompt), use [C-x o] to switch to the next tmux pane on the same window.
- If a tmux pane is focused and emacsclient **is focused** as well, then let emacs handles [C-x o].

tmux.conf:

```bsh
is_emacs='echo "#{pane_current_command}" | grep -iqE "emacs"'
bind -Temacs-keys o if-shell "$is_emacs" "send C-x; send" "select-pane -t :.+"
bind -Temacs-keys Any { send C-x; send }
bind -Troot C-x switch-client -Temacs-keys
```

init.el:

```lisp
;;; Tmux integration (See tmux.conf for details).
(defun id/other-window ()
  "Switch to the next window if opened, otherwise select next tmux pane."
  (interactive)
  (if (eq (next-window) (get-buffer-window))
      (call-process "tmux" nil nil nil "select-pane" "-t" ":.+")
    (other-window 1)))

(global-set-key [remap other-window] #'id/other-window)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this tmux conf to emulate the same behavior with splits.
Is uses the same shortcuts to split into different panes the window
I set the prefix to C-x, and the behavior to select the panes is similar than dealing with buffers in emacs. Give it a try and modify it yourself to feel more comfortable.

```
# remap prefix from 'C-b' to 'C-x'
unbind C-b
set-option -g prefix C-x
bind-key C-x send-prefix

# split panes using 3 and 2
bind 3 split-window -h
bind 2 split-window -v
unbind '"'
unbind %

# switch panes using Alt-arrow without prefix
bind Left select-pane -L
bind Right select-pane -R
bind Up select-pane -U
bind Down select-pane -D

# Enable switch session similar than emacs selecting buffer
unbind s
bind b choose-tree -w

# Kill window
bind k confirm kill-window

# Source the conf file
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf

# Use C-x 0 to close panel, similar than emacs when closing the splitted window
unbind 0
bind 0 kill-pane
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the must read at http://pragprog.com/book/bhtmux/tmux; you'll get anything you need
Further on, try out this:

```
# Setting the prefix from C-b to C-d 
# START:prefix
set -g prefix C-d 
# END:prefix 

# Ensure that we can send Ctrl-A to other apps 
bind C-d send-prefix 

# Free the original Ctrl-b prefix keybinding unbind C-b
unbind C-b

bind | split-window -h
bind _ split-window -v
```

And this for moving between panes:

```
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R
```

Both from the previous reference and the `man` page.

Comment: Much better now, thanks @Jason, I'll do my best next time.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how this answers my questions and would give me `C-x 2` and `C-x 3` for splitting?

Comment: Put this code in your config file along with whatever you need

Comment: @csantosb - I don't think those keys are what @frank is looking for.  Emacs splits with `Ctrl-x 2`, and switches with `Ctrl-x o`.